# Laravel Request :BadMethodCallException Method getPath does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-request

I was trying to add some validation in Request ,I get "BadMethodCallException
Method getPath does not exist" error. I am sending just null value in postman to test it.
for example:

{

"name":null

}

Here is my controller:

```
namespace Modules\Settings\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Modules\Settings\Repositories\SettingsInterface;

use Modules\Settings\Http\Requests\AddCommunicationType;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{


 public function addCommunicationType(AddCommunicationType $request)
{
        $data =  json_decode(json_encode($request->all()));
        $com=$this->settingRepo->addCommunicationType($data);
        return response()->json($com);

}
}
```

AddCommunicationType Request:

```
namespace Modules\Settings\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AddCommunicationType extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
    'name'=>'required',
    ];
}

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


public function messages() {
    return [
        'name.required' => 'Name is required.',

    ];
}

}
```

Route:

```
 Route::post('settings/addCommunicationType', 'SettingsController@addCommunicationType');
```

Comment: composer dump-autoload ; composer config:clear and make sure you have correct namespace

Comment: @LeoKelmendi tried them still same.

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra 5.5.19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 Method getPath does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589805/laravel-5-5-method-getpath-does-not-exist)