# Laravel 5.5 Method getPath does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

Installed composer and did a fresh install of a new Laravel project (laravel new test) using Laravel 5.5.22.  Calling a built in method getPath(), which worked in Laravel 5.4 with PHP 5.6, no longer works.  How can i fix it??

PHP Version:

```
7.1.11-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Composer Version and Packages:

```
kevin@kevin-lt:/usr/local/bin$ composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.5.3 (stable channel).

kevin@kevin-lt:/var/www/test$ composer show
dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir              0.1     implementation of xdg base   directory specification for php
doctrine/inflector                    v1.2.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                 1.1.0   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking...
doctrine/lexer                        v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Pa...
egulias/email-validator               2.1.3   A library for validating emails against several RFCs
erusev/parsedown                      1.6.4   Parser for Markdown.
fideloper/proxy                       3.3.4   Set trusted proxies for Laravel
filp/whoops                           2.1.14  php error handling for cool kids
fzaninotto/faker                      v1.7.1  Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
hamcrest/hamcrest-php                 v2.0.0  This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
jakub-onderka/php-console-color       0.1    
jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.3.2 
laravel/framework                     v5.5.22 The Laravel Framework.
laravel/tinker                        v1.0.2  Powerful REPL for the Laravel framework.
league/flysystem                      1.0.41  Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
mockery/mockery                       1.0     Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework for use in unit ...
monolog/monolog                       1.23.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
mtdowling/cron-expression             v1.2.1  CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a CR...
myclabs/deep-copy                     1.7.0   Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nesbot/carbon                         1.22.1  A simple API extension for DateTime.
nikic/php-parser                      v3.1.2  A PHP parser written in PHP
paragonie/random_compat               v2.0.11 PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phar-io/manifest                      1.0.1   Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                       1.0.1   Library for handling version information and constraints
phpdocumentor/reflection-common       1.0.1   Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     4.2.0   With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocB...
phpdocumentor/type-resolver           0.4.0  
phpspec/prophecy                      1.7.3   Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage             5.2.4   Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality f...
phpunit/php-file-iterator             1.4.5   FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template             1.2.1   Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                     1.0.9   Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream              2.0.2   Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                       6.5.0   The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects          5.0.0   Mock Object library for PHPUnit
psr/container                         1.0.0   Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/log                               1.0.2   Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                      1.0.0   Common interfaces for simple caching
psy/psysh                             v0.8.15 An interactive shell for modern PHP.
ramsey/uuid                           3.7.1   Formerly rhumsaa/uuid. A PHP 5.4+ library for generating RFC 4122 version 1...
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup    1.0.1   Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                  2.1.0   Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                        2.0.1   Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                 3.1.0   Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                    3.1.0   Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                2.0.0   Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator           3.0.3   Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced ob...
sebastian/object-reflector            1.1.1   Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ...
sebastian/recursion-context           3.0.0   Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations         1.0.0   Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                     2.0.1   Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
swiftmailer/swiftmailer               v6.0.2  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/console                       v3.4.0  Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                  v3.4.0  Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                         v3.4.0  Symfony Debug Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v4.0.0  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/finder                        v3.4.0  Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation               v3.4.0  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v3.4.0  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-mbstring             v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php70                v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/process                       v3.4.0  Symfony Process Component
symfony/routing                       v3.4.0  Symfony Routing Component
symfony/translation                   v3.4.0  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/var-dumper                    v3.4.0  Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
theseer/tokenizer                     1.1.0   A small library for converting tokenized PHP source code into XML and poten...
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles     2.2.0   CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files i...
vlucas/phpdotenv                      v2.4.0  Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVE...
webmozart/assert                      1.2.0   Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
```

Controllers/PagesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function home(Router $route){

        $this->filterRoutes($route);
    }

    public function filterRoutes($route) {
        $r = $route->getRoutes();
        foreach ($r as $value) {

            dd($value->getPath());

        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
[2017-11-30 21:00:18] local.ERROR: Method getPath does not exist.  {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method getPath does not exist. at /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:96)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/test/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->__call('getPath', Array)
#1 /var/www/test/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php(17): App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController->filterRoutes(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Router))
#2 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController->home(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Router))
#3 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('home', Array)
#5 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController), 'home')
#6 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#7 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#8 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#31 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /var/www/test/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#51 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /var/www/test/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the URI using `$value->uri`.

```
$r = $route->getRoutes();
foreach ($r as $value) {

    echo($value->uri());
}
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Comment: I've changed $value->getPath() to $value->uri() and it now errors out on my next method call, (not in original post).  It now says Method getMethods does not exist.  Have these methods (getPath and getMethods) been deprecated?   



    return [
            'path' => $value->uri(),
            'method' => $value->getMethods()[0],
            'action' => $action[1]
        ];

Comment: Looks like i might be able to substitute getMethods with the RouteCollection method.  I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: For getMethods() I was able to replace it with $value->methods[0].  It's working now.  Thank you!

Comment: Dig around the api documentation. Route has several methods for getting information about itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you work with Ubuntu operating system while working with laravel then make sure that you have give 777 permission to the folder of your project.

and first you have to write route for the getting view and then pass data on that page using post route.

like following code i have pasted here.

```
Route::get('password/change', 'UserController@reset_password_form');
Route::post('password/change', 'UserController@reset_password');
```

i have first use get method to call view page and then display or doing functionality using the post method

please feel free to ask if any doubt